# Array find an index of scanner integer

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] array = new int[5];
    array[0] = 1;
    array[1] = 3;
    array[2] = 5;
    array[3] = 7;
    array[4] = 9;

    System.out.println("Search for?");
    int searchFor = scanner.nextInt();
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length;i++)
        if(array[i] == searchFor)
            System.out.println(searchFor + " is at index " + i);
    else {
            System.out.println(searchFor + " was not found");
        }
```

I have just trouble with this and didn't find the way I can do it because most of examples require to use other functions.
But I have primitive array and I need to get an index given number by user and if it does not exist it should return `was not found`
so the problem is that my program screening all of elements all the way down and showing up 5 outcomes when I need only two outcome whether it exist in given index or not.

Comment: Use a break after you find your number to end the loop. If you haven't found your number before the end of the loop, then you tell the user that.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int[] array = new int[5];
array[0] = 1;
array[1] = 3;
array[2] = 5;
array[3] = 7;
array[4] = 9;

System.out.println("Search for?");
int searchFor = scanner.nextInt();
int index=-1;
for(int i = 0; i < array.length;i++) {
    if (array[i] == searchFor) {
        index = i;
    }
}
if(index==-1){
    System.out.println(searchFor + " was not found");
}else{
    System.out.println(searchFor + " is at index " + index);
}
```

Comment: could you tell me why you make index =-1;?

Comment: Because indexing starting from 0 in java, 0 can be a valid number of 'index'. by making index=-1, we can identify if "searchFor" number is present in Array or not.

Comment: actually your code is failing , while I give non exist number by 22 it output me that I got this number under index number 4

Comment: sorry my code was wrong , I just coincidentally put ; in my if statement thanks!~